# How to display correct input type if the property of a model is object?

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core

My view model has a `List<KeyValuePair<string, object>> mylist` property, when "object" (Value) can be either string or bool (actually it can represent a lot of other types, even not CLR).

Well, I want to render this into input tags correctly, i.e. if Value is bool, then type="checkbox" else Value is string then type="text" etc.

There is my Razor code:

```
do
{
    <input asp-for="mylist[i].Value" />
    i++;
} while (i < (int)count);
```

However such code returns a `<input type="text" />` input tag for both bool or string types. Does it exist any approach to display appropriate tag max cleanly (without any manual checking)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use GetType() as below.

```
object value = true;
if(value.GetType()==typeof(string))
{
     //Textbox
}
else if(value.GetType()==typeof(bool))
{
     //checkbox
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the full example for both CLR and custom (your own) object types. Just copy and paste into your Razor view and fill up rest of the types:

```
@model List<KeyValuePair<string, object>>

<div>
    @foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> item in Model)
    {
        Type type = item.Value.GetType();

        switch (Type.GetTypeCode(type))
        {
            case TypeCode.Boolean:
                {
                    <input type="checkbox"/>
                    break;
                }
            case TypeCode.String:
                {
                    <input type="text"/>
                    break;
                }
            default:
            {
                if (type == typeof (MyCustomType))
                {
                    ...
                }
                else if (type == typeof (MyOtherType))
                {
                    ...
                }
            }
        }
    }
</div>
```